# How to properly install mysql on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql

I tried installing MySQL on my machine (`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`
) but after installation I cannot get it to run. When I enter `mysql`  or `mysql -u root` command I receive the error 
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`.

I tried following the tutorials online and I noticed that I'm not asked to created a password during installation as mentioned online. I had a lamp stack before which I got rid of. I'm now reinstalling MySQL which I want to use for web development (JavaEE/Spring). Can anybody shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try these links: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/mysql.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run

Comment: can you add some log file too while starting mysql server: `cat /var/log/mysql/error.log` few last line so we can see error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through with following steps

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server

sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

You need to check MySQL servics running or not.

```
 sudo service mysql start
```

Check status by executing

```
sudo service mysql status
```

Then then

```
 mysql
```

Or check which port used during instllation

```
 mysql -h localhost --port 3306 - u root -p
```

you can also use MySQLTuner by executing:

```
 sudo apt-get install mysqltuner
```

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, this one actually solved my issue. One thing to note is that I had to remove mysql and urge it. Otherwise the installation will fail every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the MySQL official documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-fresh-install)

Comment: Please expand your answer to make it useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to install mysql on ubuntu , just follow these steps to properly install mysql :

**Step 1 :** update the system

```
sudo apt update
```

**Step 2 :** Install mysql package

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

**Step 3 :** Once the installation is completed, the MySQL service will start automatically. To check whether the MySQL server is running, type:

```
sudo systemctl status mysql
```

The output of the following command should be :

```
OUTPUT
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-06-20 11:30:23 PDT; 5min ago
Main PID: 17382 (mysqld)
    Tasks: 27 (limit: 2321)
CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
       `-17382 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

**Step 4 :** Securing MySQL

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

select one of the three levels of password validation policy(strong recommended).Set your password ,and then type y(yes) to all the questions , this will improve the security .

**Step 5 :** Once it has done. open MySQL by typing the following command :

```
sudo mysql
```

**Step 6 :** If you want to login to your MySQL server as root from an external program such as phpMyAdmin , then type these commands inside mysql.

```
mysql>ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'strong_password';
mysql>FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql>exit;
```

After this you will be successfully able to run mysql , for this open terminal and type.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Now type your password.

Congo! you are done with installing mysql.